# Let $0 ≤ a, b, c, d ≤ 1$. Prove that at least one of the products $a(1 − b), b(1 − c), c(1 − d), d(1 − a)$ is $\leq \frac{1}{4}$ .

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

From this question, I can tell that it's obvious that one of the products would be less than $\frac{1}{4}$. However I have a hard time trying to prove it. This supposedly uses AM GM Inequality. Can someone kindly help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you think it's obvious?  If you can work out exactly what makes you think so, this could be the idea behind a proof.

Comment: By AM-GM inequality, $$\sqrt[8]{a(1-a)b(1-b)c(1-c)d(1-d)} \le \frac{a+(1-a)+b+(1-b)+c+(1-c)+d+(1-d)}{8}$$.

Comment: If the contrary that all those 4 products are $>1/4$, then $$a(1-b)b(1-c)c(1-d)d(1-a) > \frac{1}{4^4}$$.